# SQL Server query performance when there's a dynamic condition in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say we have query A:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM MyTable WHERE Date_Created < DATEADD(DD, 3, GETDATE())
```

AND query B:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM MyTable WHERE Date_Created < '2013-05-24'
```

When those queries are run, how does the compiler optimize query A? Does it **re-evaluate** DATEADD and GETDATE for each row in **MyTable**?

The reason I am asking is because I **ran several tests** to see which queries are faster and the result seems to indicate that there's **no huge difference** in the performance of the two, which is kinda counter-intuitive. Thanks.

Comment: On how much records did you run the test ? There will probably be a performance difference, but so tiny you can only see it on a huge amount of records... Also, the first seems better to me as you're comparing dates and dates, while I'm not sure if the second isn't going to get you into trouble if your date field is indexed and you've got a lot of records

Comment: Note that these queries aren't the same - `DATEADD(DAY, 3, GETDATE())` is some time on May 24th, not May 24th at midnight. Also please don't use `DD` - just spell out `DAY`. Why? Try `SELECT DATEPART(Y, GETDATE())` to see why the abbreviations are not always what you think they will be. Finally, `YYYY-MM-DD` is not a safe format; try using `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;` and see what happens. You should use `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: @Bartdude the second format will be no problem - the literal will be properly interpreted / evaluated as a date/datetime.

Comment: Not sure why it would be considered counter-intuitive.  For the purposes of a single, atomic, query - `DATEADD(DD, 3, GETDATE())` is not dependent on row information, it can be evaluated once (even before the query is actually executed).  I suspect you'd see an impact, however, if some of the input to that function (e.g. the 3) actually came from row data.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. It makes sense now since the condition is evaluated only once.

Comment: @AaronBertrand > Thanks for the info. I've recently discovered this possible issue with indexes. Do you have some link I could check to understand better how the different queries would be interpreted and the values being automatically casted ?

Comment: As a side note, `MySQL` keeps two versions of this function: `NOW()` (aka `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`) and `SYSDATE()`. The first is evaluated once per statement (and can even be explicitly assigned the value to return), the second one always returns wall clock time and is reevaluated for each row. I wish `SQL Server` had this functionality too.

Comment: @Quassnoi - You can wrap `GETDATE()` in a scalar UDF to have it re-evaluated per row.

Comment: @MartinSmith: sure, as long as you have rights for that. And this won't affect existing queries.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Yes you wouldn't be able to replace existing `GETDATE()` queries with it if that is the intention as calls to scalar UDFs in a `SELECT` need to be schema qualified anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I'm actually missing `SET TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 3):

`GETDATE` is a [runtime constant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx) and won't be repeatedly re-evaluated.

Chances are that the whole expression with `DATEADD` will be only evaluated once.